# Parse.com Error creating a pointer object

Tags: javascript, android, database, parse-platform

I want to create a pointer object of class Item with ObjectID. I wan't to use this pointer object as a field for OrderDetails. Have a look at the code below

```
        var arr = [];
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(orderList);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            var counter = jsonData[i];

            var orderDetail = new Parse.Object("OrderDetails");
            orderDetail.set("quantity",counter.qty);

            var Item = Parse.Object.extend("Item");
            var pointerToItem = new Item();

            pointerToItem.id = counter.id;

            orderDetail.set("which_item",Item);
            orderDetail.set("which_order",myOrder);
            orderDetail.set("isProcessed",false);

            arr.push(orderDetail)    
        }
```

When i try to run this loop I am getting this error:

**Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject**

I have tried to do the same thing in Android with the following code

```
List<ParseObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < buyItems.size(); i++) {
ParseObject orderDetailObj = new ParseObject("OrderDetails");
orderDetailObj.put("quantity", item.getQty());
orderDetailObj.put("which_item", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Item", item.getId()));
orderDetailObj.put("which_order", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Order", orderObj.getObjectId()));
orderDetailObj.put("isProcessed", false);


objectList.add(orderDetailObj);
}
```

the android code is working, can you tell me what do I need to do to make the android thing work in parse cloud javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
var itemPointer = {
  __type: 'Pointer',
  className: 'Item',
  objectId: counter.id
}
```

set like
`orderDetail.set("which_item",itemPointer );`

Comment: why are you not creating item first??

Comment: So I created one as a raw JS item as you suggested and saved that in a new parse item and now it works. Thanks